# Count request on 3 tables

Tags: mysql

Here is my problem. I have 3 tables like

```
AUTHORS
    id (INT, PRIMARY KEY)
    name (VARCHAR)

WRITINGS
    id (INT, PRIMARY KEY)
    content (TEXT)
    author_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY)

COMMENTS
    id (INT)
    commentary (TEXT)
    author_id (INT, FOREIGN KEY)
```

I know how to count how many writings OR how many comments belong to each user, with these requests:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, COUNT(W.id)
FROM AUTHORS AS A
LEFT JOIN WRITINGS AS W
    ON A.id = W.author_id
GROUP BY A.id;

SELECT A.id, A.name, COUNT(C.id)
FROM AUTHORS AS A
LEFT JOIN COMMENTS AS C.author_id
    ON A.id = C.author_id
GROUP BY A.id;
```

But is there a way to obtain these two counts (writings and comments) in a unique request?

Additional challenge : same question, but WITHOUT nested request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that the simplest way is to go with two dependent subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Put one of the queries in a subquery, and join it with the others.

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, IFNULL(COUNT(W.id), 0) AS writing_count, IFNULL(C.comment_count, 0) AS comment_count
FROM AUTHORS AS A
LEFT JOIN WRITINGS AS W
    ON A.id = W.author_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT author_id, COUNT(*) AS comment_count
    FROM COMMENTS
    GROUP BY author_id) AS C
    ON A.id = C.author_id
GROUP BY A.id
```

Comment: **Thank you**, it works perfectly on my real (more complicated) tables. Now I can go on with creating stored procedures and more.